# Stuck on Level 2 Question 24

Tags: think-different

I absolutely have no idea how to solve this question 24 in level 2.

This is the question:

```
134 = 2
222 = 4
101 = 8
333 = 1
712 = ??
```

Comment: The way think different writes their questions pains me.

Answer (score 10):

If you add up all four number in each example equation, you get 10:

```
1+3+4+2=10
2+2+2+4=10
1+0+1+8=10
3+3+3+1=10
```

So for the last one it would be:

```
7+1+2+X=10
```

7+1+2 is already 10, so X is 0.

Comment: I found that having a [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) in these types of comments helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its 0. The right hand side is such a number that when added with the single digit sum(or mod 10 sum of the digits) of the left number is 1.